# Changing color of align* environment

Tags: color, align

I have this text that I want to include in my LaTeX document. I only want to change the color of the equations in the align* environment, but when I do it changes the color for the rest of the document.

Here is a minimal tex document:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\color{blue}{\begin{align*}
\tau_1 -\frac{1}{2}(\tau_2 + \tau_3) & \in \left( -0.035 -\frac{1}{2}(2.70) 
-\frac{1}{2}(1.99) \pm \sqrt{(3-1)(4.26)} \sqrt{ 0.081 \left( \frac{1^2 +(- 
\frac{1}{2})^2 + (-\frac{1}{2})^2}{4} \right) } \right) \\
\tau_1 -\frac{1}{2}(\tau_2 + \tau_3) & \in \left( -2.38 \pm \sqrt{8.52} 
\sqrt{0.081(0.375)} \right) = \left( -2.38 \pm 2.92 \sqrt{0.30} \right) = 
(-2.38 \pm 1.60)\\
\tau_1 -\frac{1}{2}(\tau_2 + \tau_3) & \in (-3.98, -0.78)
\end{align*}}

I do not want this text to be blue, but it still is blue. Why?

\end{document}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do proper grouping (around the color block) because `\color` does not have a second argument (in contrast to `\textcolor`) but acts as a switch.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

{\color{blue}\begin{align*}
\tau_1 -\frac{1}{2}(\tau_2 + \tau_3) & \in \left( -0.035 -\frac{1}{2}(2.70) 
-\frac{1}{2}(1.99) \pm \sqrt{(3-1)(4.26)} \sqrt{ 0.081 \left( \frac{1^2 +(- 
\frac{1}{2})^2 + (-\frac{1}{2})^2}{4} \right) } \right) \\
\tau_1 -\frac{1}{2}(\tau_2 + \tau_3) & \in \left( -2.38 \pm \sqrt{8.52} 
\sqrt{0.081(0.375)} \right) = \left( -2.38 \pm 2.92 \sqrt{0.30} \right) = 
(-2.38 \pm 1.60)\\
\tau_1 -\frac{1}{2}(\tau_2 + \tau_3) & \in (-3.98, -0.78)
\end{align*}}
I do not want this text to be blue, but it still is blue. Why?

\end{document}
```

Comment: Try removing the blank line before `I do not...` There is a sporious space after the color group

Comment: This does work in a LaTeX document. I should have mentioned that I am trying to do this in an R Markdown file, which uses LaTeX; this fix works in LaTeX but not R Markdown. However, I should probably take that over to Stack Exchange, since it is not strictly LaTeX; I will give you a checkmark.

Comment: Did you compile it after you removed the blank line? you're probably missing a `%` after `\end{align*}}`